# Determine the $\angle(\vec{a},\vec{b}),\;a\ne0,b\ne0$ under given conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Determine the $\angle(\vec{a},\vec{b}),\;a\ne0,b\ne0$ if $\left(\vec{a}+3\vec{b}\right)\perp\left(2\vec{a}-\vec{b}\right)$ and $\left(\vec{a}+7\vec{b}\right)\perp\left(2\vec{a}+\vec{b}\right)$.

I've seen a solution that starts with :

$5\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}=3\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}−2\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}$ and $15\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=−7\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}-2\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}$

Where you're supposed to subtract the second equation from the first, but how do you get $5\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}$ for example and why are $-7\vec{b}$ and $-2\vec{a}$ negative even when there's no negative signs in the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this solution, we will assume that $b$ is a unit vector. This does not affect the solution since the magnitude of $a$ is still unbounded, and vectors can be scaled without affecting the angle between them.

Two vectors are perpendicular if and only if their dot product is 0. Then, we have:

$(a + 3b)\cdot(2a - b) = 0$

$(a + 7b)\cdot(2a + b) = 0$

Expanding the first equation:

$(a + 3b)_{x}(2a - b)_{x} + (a + 3b)_{y}(2a - b)_{y}=0$

$(a_{x} + 3b_{x})(2a_{x}-b_{x}) + (a_{y} + 3b_{y})(2a_{y}-b_{y})=0$

$2a_{x}^{2}+5a_{x}b_{x}-3b_x^2+2a_{y}^{2}+5a_{y}b{y}-3b_{y}^{2}=0$

Rearranging:

$2(a_{x}^{2}+a_{y}^{2}) + 5(a_{x}b_{x}+a_{y}b_{y}) - 3(b_{x}^{2} + b_{y}^{2}) = 0$

$5(a_{x}b_{x} + a_{y}b_{y}) = 3(b_{x}^{2} + b_{y}^{2}) - 2(a_{x}^{2} + a_{y}^{2})$

Now, we see that we can convert back to dot-product form.

$5(a\cdot b) = 3(b\cdot b) - 2(a\cdot a)$

This is how you obtain your solution's first equation. Now, we do the same with our second equation, obtaining:

$15(a\cdot b) = -7(b\cdot b) - 2(a\cdot a)$

Because $\left\vert\vert b\vert\right\vert = 1$, and a vector's dot product with itself is its magnitude squared, we have:

$5(a\cdot b) = 3 - 2(a\cdot a)$

$15(a\cdot b) = -7 - 2(a\cdot a)$

Multiplying the first equation by 3, and then subtracting the secod equation from it, we obtain:

$0 = 16 - 4(a\cdot a)$

Because a vector's dot product with itself is its magnitude squared:

$4\left\vert\vert a\vert\right\vert^{2} = 16$

$\left\vert\vert a\vert\right\vert^{2} = 4$

$\left\vert\vert a\vert\right\vert = 2$

Now, we can substitute back into our first equation:

$5(a\cdot b) = 3(b\cdot b) - 2(a\cdot a)$

$5(a\cdot b) = 3\left\vert\vert b\vert\right\vert^{2} - 2\left\vert\vert a\vert\right\vert^{2}$

$5(a\cdot b) = 3(1)^{2} - 2(2)^{2}$

$5(a\cdot b) = -5$

$a\cdot b = -1$

$\left\vert\vert a\vert\right\vert\left\vert\vert b\vert\right\vert\text{cos }(\theta) = -1$

$2\text{cos }(\theta) = -1$

$\text{cos }(\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}$

$\theta = \text{cos }^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2}) = \boxed{120^{\circ}}$

Answer (score 0):

$v$ perpendicular to $u$ means $v.u=0$. So by that we have $(a+3b).(2a-b)=2a.a-a.b+6b.a-3b.b=0$ same for the second

Answer (score 0):

The information given enable us to write down $$(a+3b)\cdot (2a-b)=0 $$

$$(a+7b)\cdot (2a+b)=0$$

Expand them and you should be able to obtain those equations.

Answer (score 0):

$$(\vec a+3 \vec b).(2\vec a-\vec b)=0 \implies 2 a^2+6(\vec b.\vec a)-(\vec a. \vec b)-3b^2=0 \implies 5(\vec a,\vec b)=3b^2-2a^2~~~(1) $$ 
Next
$$(2\vec a+ \vec b).(\vec a+7 \vec b)=0 \implies 15(\vec a. \vec b)=-7b^2-2a^2~~~(2)$$.
Dividing (1) and (2) we get $2b=a$
From Eq.(1), we get $$5ab \cos \theta=-5 b^2 \implies \cos \theta= -\frac{b}{a}=-\frac{1}{2} \implies \theta=2\pi/3$$

Comment: I don't think $a$ and $b$ can be unit vectors. You are forgetting that $a+7b$ is perpendicular to $2a+b$.

Comment: @TonyK You masee nty Answer now, thanks.

Comment: $a+3b$ in your second line should be $2a+b$. And I don't know what you mean by $2b=a$.

Comment: @TonyK Usually, $a$ and $b$ are modulus (scalar) of $\vec a, \vec b$ respectfully. I will check you other point.

Comment: TonyK Corrected the typo now.